# the child element must occur at least two times

Tags: xml, dtd

Current element declaration:

```
<!ELEMENT personnes (person+) >
```

How can I modify it to require at least 2 `person` child elements (or more)?

Invalid:

```xml
<personnes>
<person></person>
</personnes>
```

Valid:

```xml
<personnes>
<person></person>
<person></person>
</personnes>
```

Comment: And your problem/question is what?!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<!ELEMENT personnes (person,person+) >
```